# Is there a master list of LG TV RS232 commands available somewhere?

Tags: rs232, tv

I have a LG OLED65C7P TV and for aesthetics reasons, I'm trying to force the TV to use the analog audio input (multiplexed with composite video input on a 3.5mm jack) for direct analog audio playback through the internal speakers (no matter what is going on with HDMI, ARC, or internal app audio.)  I'm hoping there is some way to do this through the RS232 input.  Maybe there is a way to do this with settings menu but I cannot find it.  Thinking that there is a "SERVICE" description on the RS232, I'm hoping I can force the TV to play analog audio to the internal speakers in a special forced mode.  Anyway to do this?

Comment: It's highly doubtful you would be able to find any such information or that it is even possible.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [LG OLED Manual](https://static.bhphotovideo.com/lit_files/332136.pdf#page=20).  27 commands mostly dealing with picture quality.

If you cannot see it under setup, odds are that what you want does not exist.  USB and RS-232 are just alternate ways to control existing features, not super-user mode.

Comment: +1 If there is a place where the OP can find if what he intends to do is possible to do, this place is this manual. I wished I have a LG TV just for the pleasure of experimenting with this commands.

Comment: @mguima A part of me does also, but I know I would be disappointed.  I'd like to see Android meets TV.

Comment: Since I wrote the comment I searched (and found) about Samsung serial commands (my TV is Samsung's). Maybe I'll plug it to a serial cable just for "playing" - I **know** that there will not be anything useful to do with this connection; I do not have great expectations, so, less disappointment. ;-)